# Return file or plain text

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I have to create a rest web service where in user access data using url. Url has a query parameter named `format` which can be either `text` or `file`. If user chooses `text` as `format` then I have to return text data to browser or if user chooses `file` as `format` then return a file for user to download. How can I achieve this?

What I have tried so far (not working) :

```
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM})
@Path("/some_path")
public Response some_path (@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
    String format = null;
    if(request.getParameterValues("format") != null && request.getParameterValues("format")[0] != null) {
        format = request.getParameterValues("format")[0].toString(); 
    }
    else {
        format = "text";
    }
    File file = new File("/some/file/path.txt");
    if(format.equals("text")) {
        return Response.status(200).entity("sending some text").build();
    } else {
        return Response.ok(file, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).header("content-disposition","attachment; filename = result.txt").build();
    }
}
```

With above code `format=text` works properly but `format=file` throws `HTTP Status 406 null` error.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP status you get is

```
406 Not Acceptable
```

To quote [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes):

> The requested resource is only capable of generating content not acceptable according to the Accept headers sent in the request.

So you client doesn't send a HTTP header of

```
Accept: text/plain
```

or

```
Accept: application/octet-stream
```

or any combination. Check your client and the header it sends.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing to approaches. The first, quite popular but not standardized, by providing the hint of the expected result in request's path by using the `format` parameter (BTW you may use the `@QueryParam("format") String format` rather than extracting it from `ServletRequest`). The second approach is the HTTP content negotiation mechanism, in this case using `Accept/Content-Type` headers. This mechanism is handled by the JAX-RS implementation based on `@Produces` annotation and providers' classes.

So now, your user is not only required to set the `format` but also `Accept` header. It seems that you are using the client which sets the `Accept` and one of its value is `text/plain`. That is why it the first case is working, but there is no `application/octet-stream` or `*/*` (all), so you the JAX-RS expects that the client is not able to process such a content and instead sends him an error `406 Not Acceptable`.

The solution here is to remove the `@Produces` annotation (you are the one who is taking care of the format of the response), or drop the `format` parameter and let the JAX-RS do his work (probably you will need to register your own provider). If you however stay with your solution then make sure that the correct or no Accept header is send in request (no header means:  "I would accept whatever you send").